# SoapUI - Apply DataSource Loop to two excel sheets

Tags: soapui

I have a SoapUI script that is designed to compare two service calls. Right now all I have to use is the legacy service (the expected values). I'm calling the legacy system with a datasource to drive test cases.

I'm using a second datasouce as a **stub** to mimic the new service while it's being developed.

Looping through the legacy service data works fine with the one data source but the problem is when I try to access the second datasource in the loop, it won't iterate.

The test structure looks like this:

```
       Legacy DataSource
|----> Legacy Call
|      New Service Stub (Excel DataSource) 
|      Some Validation
|      DataSink (Trying to access the New Service Stub)
|<-----Legacy DataSource Loop
```

When I try to access the Service Stub (Excel Sheet) from the DataSink, I only get blank values - it appears like the test step to retrieve the data is never running or SoapUI never incrementsthe row #.

How can I step through the second datasource inside an existing loop?

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been bumped back to the homepage.  I described how SoapUI can loop over two data sources.  The person who asked the question came up with their own solution of simply creating a single data source.

Comment: @ChrisAdams very true. This has fallen through the cracks. Adding my own answer and upvoting yours so this can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was with my understanding of how these loop structures work. I solved this by putting all required data into 1 excel book and iterating over that one data source.

Answer (score 1):

You need a second data source loop.  It’s the loop that enables the iteration over the data source and you have one for the legacy datasource, but not one for the ‘stub.

```
       Legacy DataSource
|----> Legacy Call
|  |-> New Service Stub (Excel DataSource) 
|  |   Some Validation
|  |   DataSink (Trying to access the New Service Stub)
|  |-> Inner loop to Some Validation step
|<-----Legacy DataSource Loop
```

Comment: The problem is I need the data to be parallel. I've since realized I should just put all of the data in the same excel sheet.